# How to restart my game with user input of 'y'? Created a user defined function for after-game

Tags: python, user-input

```
i=1
```

## Play Another or Quit Game

```
def done():

    quitvalue=str(input("Play Again?(y/n):"))
    if quitvalue=='n' and i==0:
            SystemExit
    elif quitvalue=="y":
                i=1



#Loop to Restart Game

def rps(play1,play2):

        #Check Winner of Game
        if play1==play2:
            print("It's a tie!")
            done()

        elif play1=='r':
            if play2=='s':
                print(play1name+" Wins!")
                done()

            else:
                print(play2name+" Wins!")
                done()


        elif play1=='p':
            if play2=='r':
                print(play1name+" Wins!")
                done()

            else:
                print(play2name+" Wins!")
                done()

        elif play1=='s':
            if play2=='p':
                print(play1name+" Wins!")
                done()

            else:
                print(play2name+" Wins!")
                done()


#Player Input
while i==1:
    play1name=str(input("Player 1 Name?:"))
    play2name=str(input("Player 2 Name?:"))
    play1= str(input(play1name+" Choose Rock(r),Paper(p), Scissors(s):"))
    play2= str(input(play2name+" Choose Rock(r),Paper(p), Scissors(s):"))
    i=0
    rps(play1,play2)
```

Comment: Update: I know I'm doing something wrong with the loop. I have no idea how to restart the game though without making the #Player Input portion a user defined function.

Comment: No errors popping up. Just ends the program regardless of user response (y/n).

Comment: The `i=1` inside the `done` function refers to a new `i` which is local to that function. It has nothing to do with the variable named `i` in your global code at the end of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `i` in the `done()` function refers to a variable `i` that is being declared locally in the function by deafult, not the global variable `i` declared at the beginning of your program.  To fix this issue, add `global i` in your `done()` function prior to `i` being referenced there:

```
def done():
    global i
    quitvalue=str(input("Play Again?(y/n):"))
    if quitvalue=='n' and i==0:
            SystemExit
    elif quitvalue=="y":
                i=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to `raise SystemExit` in your `done()` function to exit?

If so, you don't need to track your ambiguously named variable `i` and deal with scoping problems. See [here for some useful explanation](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html).

You should also move your player name inputs out of your game loop and `input()` will return a string.

I've tidied the code and removed some of the unnecessarily repeated sections.

```
def done():
    """Prompt user to continue or exit"""
    quit_value = input("Play Again?(y/n): ").lower()
    if quit_value == 'n':
        raise SystemExit

def rps(play1, play2):
    """Play a single round of Rock, Paper, Scissors"""
    # Check Winner of Game
    if play1 == play2:
        print("It's a tie!")
    elif play1 == 'r':
        if play2 == 's':
            print(play1name + " Wins!")
        else:
            print(play2name + " Wins!")
    elif play1 == 'p':
        if play2 == 'r':
            print(play1name + " Wins!")
        else:
            print(play2name + " Wins!")
    elif play1 == 's':
        if play2 == 'p':
            print(play1name + " Wins!")
        else:
            print(play2name + " Wins!")

# get player names
play1name = input("Player 1 Name?: ")
play2name = input("Player 2 Name?: ")
# Player Input
while True:  # done() exits the program, so loop forever
    play1 = input(play1name + " Choose Rock(r),Paper(p), Scissors(s): ")
    play2 = input(play2name + " Choose Rock(r),Paper(p), Scissors(s): ")
    # resolve the plays
    rps(play1, play2)
    # check for a rematch
    done()
```

You might also want to check for valid moves in the `rps()` function.